# Get auto incremented value from INSERT statement and assigning it to PHP

Tags: oracle, zend-framework

I am using Zend framework and Oracle, below is my save() function

```
public function save()
{

  $time = strtotime($_POST['DeliveryDate']);
  $deliveryDate = date('d-M-Y',$time);

  try{
  $result = '';
  $dml = "INSERT INTO NOBL_TEC_EFT(SNO_PK, ITEM, ITEM_TYPE, QUANTITY, UNIT_PRICE, NEED_BY_DATE, SITE, DELIVER_TO_LOCATION, AFE, TASK, REQUESTOR, ATTRIBUTE1, ATTRIBUTE2) VALUES (Sno_seq.nextval, '".$_POST['Item']."', '".$_POST['ItemType']."', ".(int)$_POST['Quantity'].", ".(int)$_POST['TotalPrice'].", '".$deliveryDate ."', '".$_POST['Site']."', '".$_POST['DeliverToLoc']."', '".$_POST['Afe']."', 'Task', '".$_POST['Requestor']."', '".$_POST['CodeOne']."', '".$_POST['CodeTwo']."')";

  $query = Application_Model_DbTable_Eftrqsthead::getDefaultAdapter();
  // echo $dml;
  $query = $query->query($dml);

      if($query){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }

  }catch(Exception $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
  }

}
```

Above in my INSERT statement am inserting SNO_PK as auto incremented value, what I want to do here is I want to get the SNO_PK value from that INSERT statement and assign it to a PHP variable, then return it. I am new to Oracle, any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

I have seen RETURNING clause but didn't understood how to use it in my case.

Comment: Run a `select Sno_seq.currval from dual` after the insert.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how to return that value from PHP?

Comment: Like any other SELECT statement. Sorry I don't know PHP

Answer (score 0):

Check `get_class_methods($query)` and you will find something like `$query->lastInsertId();`.

PS. Watch out how you put variables into your SQL. Short way to SQLInjection ;)

Comment: Am using oracle, not mysql.

Comment: Manual says this function will work with Oracle if you provide 2 parameters (table name, column_name) which are part of sequence. If you have followed the convention that a sequence is named using the table and column names for which the sequence generates values, and a suffix "_seq". If the name of your sequence object does not follow this naming convention, use the lastSequenceId() method instead. This method takes a single string argument, naming the sequence literally. Link --> http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.write.lastinsertid

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple, while you are executing query, suddenly you will get its last (incremented value). I have implemented your code.

```
$query = Application_Model_DbTable_Eftrqsthead::getDefaultAdapter();
  // echo $dml;
  $query = $query->query($dml);

      if($query){
        echo $query;
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }

  }catch(Exception $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
  }

}
```